# Import kml file as a layer in Polymaps

Tags: d3.js, kml, polymaps

I have a kml file I want to display using polymaps. The data is from NREL Solar Resource Map.
As a kmz file it shows up quite nicely in google maps and earth respectively, however I am having trouble loading it into my polymaps/d3 environment. Does anyone know how exactly to go about this?

I can post more details if necessary

Comment: Have you seen [this example](http://techslides.com/demos/polymaps/polymaps-kml.html)?

Comment: Nice, very helpful I will especially explore the Geocommons site. There's a pretty informative article linked to the example. Thanks